# How Do I Restore WP site from unzipped files and SQL dump?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, migration

I have a site I am supposed to migrate. The previous developer did not give me access to the Wordpress backend or a Wordpress back up file. I do, however, have access to FTP for the site. I've downloaded all of the site files including Wordpress, plugins, the theme, and I have a SQL dump file of the database. How can I restore the site (at another location) with these elements?

Comment: *"The previous developer did not give me access to the Wordpress backend or a Wordpress back up file. I do, however, have access to FTP for the site."*  Sounds like you illegal downloaded the source code? Or did i misread this?

Comment: No - we had permission to access everything we had log in for. The original developer just "went missing" for a number of months so we're trying to finish the site.

Comment: Basically a case of 'we're locked out of our own site' except for FTP access. There's a SQL dump in the main directory, so at least we have something to go on re: db. I've never restored from a incomplete back up file (the types that work with WP plugins). So not really sure where to start.

Comment: This isn't a programming question so it's not a good question for Stack Overflow. But you might try the [WordPress StackExchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). I also found this guide by a google search for the keywords "wordpress transfer site": https://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/

Comment: FWIW, I have encountered your situation quite a few times. The story usually sounds like, "We paid a developer to set up a wordpress site for us, but he gave us no admin access or instructions, and then he ghosted us and won't return phone calls."

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin I'll try moving the question there. Ya i've migrated sites before. I'm working with an incomplete set of files. I'm sure someone knows how to do this it just isn't really my expertise.

Comment: And ya - that's pretty much how it went. He gave us FTP access so at least we have something. But ya. Thanks.

Comment: The guide Bill posted should get you on the right track. It's not that difficult, just be patient and make sure to test everything afterwards.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if there's just one individual developer setting up all these sites and abandoning their owners. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the previous site's root in tact, meaning you extracted ALL the files, and not just wp-content (if you only did this, you should just download everything from the previous root).

1) Upload zipped file to new root directory
2) Unzip the file
3) Create new database and database user
4) Import SQL dump to new database
5) In wp-config file, adjust settings to point to new database
6) In database, change primary site URL to the new site domain (may be multiple instances so do search/replace)
7) In database, [create a WP user](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/) so you can log in to Wordpress backend
8) Remove original zip file from root

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I realized I had all of the root, and then realized I just follow the basic steps of installing and pointing to a new DB etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the database you can use a MD5 hash generator to change the password of the admin user then use a duplicator package plugin to copy and migrate the site wherever you need to.